# How to pass a function and variables to Automator input?

Tags: shell, input, automator

I have a function like this one

```
myText(){
    echo "Title: ${1}"
    echo "Text: ${2}"
}
title="ABC"
text="123"
document=/tmp/temp.txt
myText "${title}" "${text}"

while read line; do
    fillText "${title}" "${text}"
done < "${document}"
```

… and an Automator workflow which receives selected text.

Formerly I used a ruby script. It was no problem to pipe the content to it like this:

```
while read line; do
    fillText "${title}" "${text}" | /usr/bin/somescript.rb
done < "${document}"
```

However, now I need to pass the content to an automator workflow.

Automator can run a workflow like this:

```
automator [-v] [-i input] [-D name=value ...] workflow
```

So I tried:

```
while read line; do
    output=$(fillText "${title}" "${text}")
    automator -i "${output}" ~/Library/Services/myAutomator.workflow
done < "${document}"
```

It doesn't work. Any of you guys know how to pull it off?

PS: The ouput has multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Tell `automator` to read from standard input by pass `-` as the argument to `-i`.

```
while read line; do
    fillText "${title}" "${text}" | automator -i - ~/Library/Services/myAutomator.workflow
done < "${document}"
```

Comment: Mh. I hoped it would look that easy and effortless. However, it didn't work with my script (see https://gist.github.com/pattulus/2c10ac10d727c1cb6fd4). Maybe it's the `env bash`?

Comment: How does it fail? What action are you using to read the input?

Comment: I updated the gist, so that it works without the inputs I pass to it. The thing is I don't get any error output even when adding the verbose option. The content of the text file is a simple Markdown link like `* [Title](http://stackoverflow.com)`.